# How to use a theme in netbeans 7.1?

Tags: themes, netbeans

I have downloaded an external theme for netbeans. How to apply it?
I am using Ubuntu 10.04(LTS)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Themes are contained in a .zip archive.

1. Open the Options window: *Tools* -> *Options* (see picture 1)
2. Press the *Import* button (see picture 1)
3. Press the *Browse* button and select the theme file (a .zip archive).
4. Tick the checkbox to select all settings (just *Fonts & Colors* will be fine as well, those are the themes) (see picture 2)
5. Press OK and accept the confirmation dialog
6. After restarting, go to *Options* again and select the theme at *Fonts & Colors*, *Profile* (see picture 1)

[image: Options dialog]

[image: Import dialog]

Comment: I appreciate such your efforts for visual explanation. thanks